# Swift Combine: no `distinct` operator?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11, combine

Seems like Combine (shipped with Xcode 11 beta 7) lacks a [`distinct`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html) operator?

Can anyone help me build one? :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ah how silly of me, there is one, it is called [`RemoveDuplicates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/removeduplicates), and [link to method `removeDuplicates()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204745-removeduplicates)

Comment: it only compares to previous element, not all previous elements

Answer (score 7):

**.removeDuplicates()** is equivalent to **.distinctUntilChanged()**

You can do the following to get **.distinct()**.

```
@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension Publisher where Self.Output : Equatable {
    public func distinct() -> AnyPublisher<Self.Output, Self.Failure> {
        self.scan(([], nil)) {
            $0.0.contains($1) ? ($0.0, nil) : ($0.0 + [$1], $1)
        }
        .compactMap { $0.1 }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```